# If the left and right hand limit of a function (x tends to a) is a finite number, but the function becomes infinity(N/0) at x=a, does the limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Suppose there's a function (y) whose graph goes like this:[image]

If at x=2, the function's value is not defined (or infinite or 'a finite number/0'), then, even though the function is infinite at that x,
'limx→a' should exist in this case, right?
If it does, then does it mean limit can exist when a function is infinity at a given 'x', even though it's not a indeterminant form?

(could be a silly doubt)

Answer (score 1):

We are studying the limit around $x_0=2$. Which is defined by $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-2|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, $x\neq 2$.

Can you see that in your case such $L$ does exist? Can you prove it? In fact it does, it just happens that $L\neq f(2)$, which has to do with the fact that the function $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

*Remark*
What is your definition of limit?  Perhaps:

$L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $0 < |x-2|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

I put "$0 < {}$" in there instead of adding the confusing "$x\neq 2$" at the end.